# sky layer cant add to MapBoxGl - QT5.12.4

Tags: javascript, json, qt5, mapbox-gl, qtlocation

i am using Mapboxgl - qml and every things is ok but i cant tilt above 45 and the sky layer cant found the code :
main.qml

```
import QtLocation 5.12
import QtPositioning 5.12
import QtQuick 2.12


Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent

        plugin: Plugin {
            name: "mapboxgl"
            PluginParameter {
                name: "mapboxgl.access_token"
                value: "pk.eyJ1IjoibWlsYWRsb3ZlYm90aCIsImEiOiJjanZiaHlrZXEwczF5NDRxZnp0cnFseG9jIn0.CZjNPyoSnkUG4NaEzvb36A"
            }
            PluginParameter{
                name: "mapboxgl.mapping.additional_style_urls"
                value: "mapbox://styles/miladloveboth/ckkpdclqt0siu17nppaymn68a"
            }
            PluginParameter {
                name: "mapboxgl.mapping.use_fbo"
                value: true
            }

            PluginParameter {
                name: "mapboxgl.mapping.items.insert_before"
                value: "aerialway"
            }
        }

        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(44.190448, 35.402046) // Helsinki
        zoomLevel: 16
        minimumZoomLevel: 0
        maximumZoomLevel: 20
        gesture.enabled: true
        tilt: 45
        activeMapType: map.supportedMapTypes[0]
         MapParameter {
            type: "paint"
            property var layer: "sky"
            property var skyType: "atmosphere"
        }
     }
```

and when i run it i got this Error:

```
    Threaded rendering is not optimal in the Mapbox GL plugin.
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [3]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [3]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [3]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [3]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [2]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [2]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [2]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [2]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [2]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [2]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [3]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [3]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [2]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [1]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: [1]: Expected arguments of type (number, number) | (string, string), but found (value, number) instead."
[ WARNING ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[ParseStyle]: invalid layer type"
Layer not found: "sky"
[ INFO ]  "{QSGRenderThread}[General]: GPU Identifier: SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM;"
```

and i added sky layer at Mapbox Studio, and i can see the Sky layer at my custom mapbox style JSON
(search with ctrl+F for "sky" and You can see it)
[custom mapbox style link](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/miladloveboth/ckkpdclqt0siu17nppaymn68a?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWlsYWRsb3ZlYm90aCIsImEiOiJjanZiaHlrZXEwczF5NDRxZnp0cnFseG9jIn0.CZjNPyoSnkUG4NaEzvb36A)
so whats my problem?
i tried this ways also and i got nothing too:

```
MapParameter {
                type: "sky"
                property var layer: "sky"
                property var skyType: "atmosphere"
            }
```

and this:

```
MapParameter {
                type: "layer"
                property var layer: "sky"
                property var paint:{
                "sky-type": "atmosphere"
                }
            }
```

and i got some error :

```
Invalid value for property 'type': 'sky'
```

**#ubuntu@uname -a**

```
Linux ubuntu 5.8.0-41-generic #46~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 17:52:23 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and the QT version is 14.13.1
so how can i use sky at my mapboxgl?
sorry for bad english - milad From IRAN - Thank you Guys

Comment: you cannot. The version shipped with Qt does not support it.

Comment: @Pa_ where to find information what does it support and what not? Qt Automotive Suite supports more or not?

Comment: The version shipped with Qt supports what the open source mapbox-gl-native supports.
Sky layer is not available there.